# Centering two boxes on resize

Tags: html, css, formatting, media-queries

I'm wondering if anyone has advice on how best to force two divs to center when a page is resized.

Here is the relevant html:

```
<div id="body">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="box1"></div>
        <div id="box2"></div>
    </div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

I generally want the box 1 and box 2 divs to be aligned to the [left and right](https://gyazo.com/727dcab9333a454d0a027fbb1a73b025) of each other. So I use the following CSS:

```
#box1, #box2
    {
        float:left;
        max-width:25em;
        min-width:20em;
        width:45%;
    }
```

The issue I am trying to resolve is how to best get them to stack and then center if the page is resized.  The desired look is:
[image: Stacked and Centered]

I know I an use a media query like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px)
    { 
        #box1, #box2
            {
                /* SOMETHING */
            }
    }
```

Comment: Replace `/*SOMETHING*/` with `width:100%;float:left;clear:both;`

Comment: Great! All these answers work. Thank you.  One last small question.  If I wanted to position them X pixels left of center, how would I achieve that result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should be put inside your media query:

- To stop them stacking next to each other you need to remove `float: left;`. This is because `div`s are `block` elements and will automatically move to a new line
- You are giving the `div`s `width` so adding `margin: 0 auto;` will enable them to be centered

```css
#box1 {
  background-color: red;
}
#box2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
#box1, #box2 {
  float: left;
  max-width: 25em;
  min-width: 20em;
  width: 45%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #box1, #box2 {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 25em;
    min-width: 20em;
    width: 45%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">Box 1</div>
<div id="box2">Box 2</div>
```

Comment: One last small question. If I wanted to position them X pixels left of center, how would I achieve that result?

Comment: @COMisHARD As you are using `margin` to center the `div`s you would need to add `position: relative;` and `left:` **n** `px;` (where **n** is the amount of pixels you want to move it by). https://jsfiddle.net/fjdr1g0e/

Answer (score 1):

Here you don't require media queries.

Try this.

```
#content {

    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
    border:thick dotted #060;
    margin: 0px auto 10px auto;
    width:100%;
}

#box1,
#box2
 {

    max-width:25em;
    min-width:20em;
    width:45%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #999;
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/pYaKB/975/)